# Fail to find JPEG when compiling cmake project for android

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake

I am trying to compile my cmake library for android, but there is a dependence on JPEG.
I was able to cross-compile jpeg for the android x86 platform, but now I am stuck with locating the binaries and headers within the cmake (`find_package(JPEG QUIET)` always failed to find the JPEG library).
JPEG sources with compiled binaries are under ~/Android/Sdk/ndk/19.2.5345600/sources/jpeg8d/
I have the next structure of the jpeg8d:

```
.
├── Android.mk
├── cderror.h
├── cdjpeg.c
├── cdjpeg.h
├── change.log
├── cjpeg.c
├── ckconfig.c
├── coderules.txt
├── config.guess
├── config.sub
├── configure
├── configure.ac
├── depcomp
├── djpeg.c
├── example.c
├── filelist.txt
├── install-sh
├── install.txt
├── jaricom.c
├── jcapimin.c
├── jcapistd.c
├── jcarith.c
├── jccoefct.c
├── jccolor.c
├── jcdctmgr.c
├── jchuff.c
├── jcinit.c
├── jcmainct.c
├── jcmarker.c
├── jcmaster.c
├── jcomapi.c
├── jconfig.bcc
├── jconfig.cfg
├── jconfig.dj
├── jconfig.h
├── jconfig.mac
├── jconfig.manx
├── jconfig.sas
├── jconfig.st
├── jconfig.txt
├── jconfig.vc
├── jconfig.vms
├── jconfig.wat
├── jcparam.c
├── jcprepct.c
├── jcsample.c
├── jctrans.c
├── jdapimin.c
├── jdapistd.c
├── jdarith.c
├── jdatadst.c
├── jdatasrc.c
├── jdcoefct.c
├── jdcolor.c
├── jdct.h
├── jddctmgr.c
├── jdhuff.c
├── jdinput.c
├── jdmainct.c
├── jdmarker.c
├── jdmaster.c
├── jdmerge.c
├── jdosabcc.obj
├── jdosamsc.obj
├── jdosaobj.txt
├── jdpostct.c
├── jdsample.c
├── jdtrans.c
├── jerror.c
├── jerror.h
├── jfdctflt.c
├── jfdctfst.c
├── jfdctint.c
├── jidctflt.c
├── jidctfst.c
├── jidctint.c
├── jinclude.h
├── jmemansi.c
├── jmemdosa.asm
├── jmemdos.c
├── jmemmac.c
├── jmemmgr.c
├── jmemname.c
├── jmemnobs.c
├── jmemsys.h
├── jmorecfg.h
├── jpeg
├── jpegint.h
├── jpeglib.h
├── jpegtran.c
├── jutils.c
├── jversion.h
├── libjpeg.map
├── libjpeg.txt
├── ltmain.sh
├── makcjpeg.st
├── makdjpeg.st
├── Makefile.am
├── makefile.ansi
├── makefile.bcc
├── makefile.dj
├── Makefile.in
├── makefile.manx
├── makefile.mms
├── makefile.sas
├── makefile.unix
├── makefile.vc
├── makefile.vms
├── makefile.wat
├── makeproj.mac
├── makljpeg.st
├── maktjpeg.st
├── makvms.opt
├── missing
├── obj
│   └── local
│           ├── libjpeg.a
│           └── objs
│               └── cocos_jpeg_static
├── rdbmp.c
├── rdcolmap.c
├── rdgif.c
├── rdjpgcom.c
├── rdppm.c
├── rdrle.c
├── rdswitch.c
├── rdtarga.c
├── README
├── readme.dos
├── structure.txt
├── testimg.bmp
├── testimg.jpg
├── testimgp.jpg
├── testimg.ppm
├── testorig.jpg
├── testprog.jpg
├── tmp
├── transupp.c
├── transupp.h
├── usage.txt
├── wizard.txt
├── wrbmp.c
├── wrgif.c
├── wrjpgcom.c
├── wrppm.c
├── wrrle.c
└── wrtarga.c
```

CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/home/ifolbort/apps/Qt/5.12.2/android_x86/home/ifolbort/Android/Sdk/ndk/19.2.5345600

Could you please point me how do I correctly feed my precompiled jpeg library to CMake project?

Comment: For make `find_package` working, you need to **install** jpeg, not just to build it. Installing is usually performed with `make install`.

Comment: Thanks, for the advice. I fixed the issue another way, by removing the redundant dependence on the package, which requires jpeg